# How to filter by index's name in ElasticSearch queries?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to run a query against two indices as following:

```
GET product,account/producttype,accounttype/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "title.keyword": {
                    "boost": 1000,
                    "query": "Bed Room"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": {
                    "value": "product"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In the query above I am using filter to filter by index's name, but when I run it I get no hits, and when I remove filter query I get hits.

So how can I create queries against multiple indices with filters by index's name?

**Update:**

When I filter by "_type": "producttype" I get hits but when I filter by "_index": "product" I get no hits.

**PS:**

I am using ElasticSearch V5.1.1

Comment: which elastic version you're using?

Comment: just tried on my local es setup and it's working. is _index query working if you completely remove other clauses?

Comment: @Mysterion For me I have tried it so much if I remove this clause  "filter": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "_index": {
                    "value": "product"
                  }
                }
              }
            ] I get hits

Comment: yes, that's i understand, but what if you remove should with title?

Comment: @Mysterion No it's still not working